How to identify swap transactions?
Is there a way to identify all swap transactions of a token pair?
So this would involve CEX, DEX, direct swaps, and other forms I am not aware of.
Of course, this can be complex involving many intermediaries and steps, but still interested if there is a primary way to do this.
Or does this always come to the smart contracts executing the token transfers? (e.g. here)
In this case, are there any good data sources listing swap transaction data (i.e. token pair, exchange rate, volume)? The APIs I reviewed, if they list transactions, do not identify swaps.
